Flutter app bypasses authentication after reinstalling on Android and iOS
I’m developing a Flutter mobile app for both Android and iOS. When I uninstall and reinstall the app, it directly navigates into the app without asking for authentication details. I expect it to prompt for login on each fresh installation, but it seems to remember the previous session details somehow.
I am using mobile number and OTP for authentication. When a user login into the app, their data is stored in local storage using flutter_secure_storage. If the user uninstalls and then reinstalls the app, it will not prompt them to login again instead, it will take them directly to the home screen

On iOS, session tokens are typically stored in keychain, which survives across app reinstallation.

How exactly are you remembering the sessions between app invocations?

Specify what "custom authentication methods" are you relying on. What's happening is most probably related to its implementation detail.

@AmalK
I am using mobile number and OTP for authentication. When a user login into the app, their data is stored in local storage. If the user uninstalls and then reinstalls the app, it will not prompt them to log in again; instead, it will take them directly to the home screen

@AkhilGeorge What are you using to store the data? Shared preferences, path provider or something else?

@AmalK flutter_secure_storage

this because Secure Storage save the data on the phone storage it self not the app which cause the issue you have now ,
you need to create another flag which help you to determine whether it's first run or not ,
this example using shared_preferences
the below is how you need to configure it
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var isFirstRun = sharedPreferences.getBool("isFirstRun") ?? true;
  if (isFirstRun) {
    const storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    await storage.deleteAll();
    sharedPreferences.setBool("isFirstRun", false);

  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}


The isFirstRun key must be set to false using sharedPreferences.setBool after calling deleteAll(). Or else, the auth state will never be persisted.

Thanks Amal for your comment yes you are right I just forget to set the flag back to false Thank you again

@aymanomara this won't help
.
.
final LocalStorage sharedPreferences = LocalStorage();
var isFirstRun =
await sharedPreferences.readValue("isFirstRun") == "false" ? false : true;
log(isFirstRun.toString());
if (isFirstRun) {
await sharedPreferences.clearAllValue();
sharedPreferences.setValue("isFirstRun", "false");
}
runApp(
const MyAppMultiProvider(myApp: MyApp()),
);

@Akhil George , Dear this solution already tested from my side on real project why this won't help?

@aymanomara Upon revisiting it, I realized that the issue wasn't with your solution but rather a fault in my implementation.
I sincerely apologize for any confusion or inconvenience caused. Your solution was indeed correct, and I truly appreciate the time and effort you took to help me out.
Thank you for your support and understanding!

@Akhil George Dear I am glad that the solution works with you and you solved your issue , no worries at all we are all here to support and help each other,  have a nice coding bro
